# How to pass a string value from JQuery AJAX request, to the Spring Boot controller?

Tags: java, jquery, json, spring-boot, controller

What I'm trying to achieve, is to retrieve the string value from the HTML input field (the one with placeholder value = 'Search NDG'), send it to the Spring Boot controller, and finally save it in the database.

Here is what I've already done:

[image]

In the success part of ajax, I can see the right value being displayed in the alert window, but right after that, I get another alert, containing 404 error code. Why does it happen? Am I still missing something in my Controller? Here's the code for that:

[image]

Thanks in advance for giving me any hint on that.

Kind regards, Mateusz

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the alert you are getting is the one which is written before Ajax call, not the success block one.

So just try to find out the exact error by debugging Ajax failure block.

Comment: Yes, you're right - the alert was actually the one before Ajax call. I just put debuggers inside the error block, between each alert, but it doesn't show any further details... Also two last lines ( alert(xhr.responseText) and alert(thrownError) ) display just an empty alert window in the browser...

Comment: use console.log for debugging purpose. Go step by step 1.check controller method is getting hit or not 2. If hitting then check it is returning correct response.